# Image comparison program (optimization required)

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, optimization

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap pic1 = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\SavedBMPs\1new.jpg");
            Bitmap pic2 = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\SavedBMPs\2new.jpg");
            if (findIN(pic1, pic2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Found\n");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static bool findIN(Bitmap pic1, Bitmap pic2)
    {
        bool found = false;
        ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0.91f);
        TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(pic1, pic2);
        BitmapData data = pic1.LockBits( new Rectangle(0, 0, pic1.Width, pic1.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pic1.PixelFormat);
        foreach (TemplateMatch m in matchings)
        {
            Drawing.Rectangle(data, m.Rectangle, Color.White);
            if (m.Rectangle.Location.X >= 0 && m.Rectangle.Location.Y >= 0)
            {
                found = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Upper Left : { X = " + (m.Rectangle.Location.X) + " , Y = " + (m.Rectangle.Location.Y) + " }");
                Console.WriteLine("Bottom Right : { X = "+(m.Rectangle.Location.X + pic2.Width) + " , Y = " + (m.Rectangle.Location.Y + pic2.Height)+" }");
            }
        }
        pic1.UnlockBits(data);
        return found;
    }
}
```

This program looks for image `2new.jpg` inside a big image `1new.jpg` and return its upper left (starting coordinates) and bottom lower (ending coordinates). The problem is that this program is too slow, taking 13.126 ms to run (especially this part: `TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(pic1, pic2);` ). Do you have any ideas/suggestions how can this function be optimized?

Comment: In the title, do you mean compression?

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your intentions.
You are trying to find a template (`pic2`) on the image (`pic1`) and use the `AForge.Net Framework`.

Assuming that the dimension "pic1" is NxM and the dimension "pic2" is KxL
The total amount of multiplication needed is proportional to **N x M x K x L** (roughly) where 'x' is multiplication.

## A simple solution is:

1. first scale the image down ("pic1") and template ("pic2") and find in the small version.
2. If you need more precision, you can srop orginall `pic1` to the region found in step 1 + margin. and calculate the match on it.
3. Found coordinates should be scaled up by the same scale.

### Example

For example, the main image `pic1` has the dimension 4000x4000 pixels, and the template "pic2" has the size 100x100 pixels.

The total number of calculations is proportional:

4000 x 4000 x 100 x 100 = 160,000,000,000.

If we reduce the size by 2 (scaledown) first, we get:

2000 x 2000 x 50 x 50 = 10,000,000,000 - which means a 160/10=16 increase in performance. (roughly)

Comment: You right, but will the (x,y) cords be alright? i mean they will definitely change.

Comment: You are right, they will be the same to the scale of image. After operation you have to scale up cords  by the same scale.